# How can I find the name of a Windows OLE object?

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module, win32ole

I'm trying to use the [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE) module to control a Windows application. I know that the developers of the application provide an OLE Object to control it, but I don't know the name of the object.

On an old version of the program, I managed to reference the object in Perl by the following line:

```
$ref = new Win32::OLE 'object.name'
```

but the new version of the program has a different object name.

Is there any way of checking which OLE objects exist for applications that are currently running on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

[Win32::OLE comes with an OLE browser](https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-OLE-0.1712/browser). Keep in mind, it only works with Internet Explorer and only when you load the HTML document from your local system.

Of course, you could also install Microsoft's development tools and get the native OLE/COM Object Viewer:

[image: Windows OLE/COM Object Viewer]

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the names and components of Win32::OLE objects for other products (Excel, Word) by starting the product, then typing `Alt-F11`.  This should open the VBA editor.  Once in the VBA editor, type F2 (or use the pull-down menu from View) to start the Object Browser. This will list the objects relevant to that product. Here is an example from Excel.

[image: Excel Object Browser]