# Java Automatization COM

Tags: java, sap-gui

I'm planning to automatize a couple SAP t-codes with java for one of my project.

Actually I'm able to open word like this :

```
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;
import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;
import com.jacob.com.Variant;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary();
            ActiveXComponent oWord = new ActiveXComponent("Word.Application");
            oWord.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(true));
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter("out.word"));
        }
    }
}
```

Which is works well.

As you can see, I'm using `com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent` this is the [doc](https://www.mvndoc.com/c/com.hynnet/jacob/com/jacob/activeX/ActiveXComponent.html).

I'm using the constructor which require a string. I think it's the easiest one to use. Now the question (probably silly) is, how/where find this string for SAP?

With the command bellow, I can start SAP GUI.

```
C:\Program` Files` `(x86`)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapshcut.exe -user='****' -pw='*****' -system='AAA' -client='444'
```

Comment: Probably this could help to find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042636/how-can-i-find-the-name-of-a-windows-ole-object